# How to identify the address of endpoint in "USB to 4-Port Serial"?

Tags: android, android-studio, serial-port, usb, android-things

I'm programming with Android Studio for an Android Things target on a Pico i.MX7Dual development board.
I have an usb-serial converter ("USB to 4-Port Serial") and I want to communicate with each of the serial ports.
I tried to use USB Host API to list the device :

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
    Log.d("USBList",device.toString());
}
```

And I obtain that in the Logcat :

```
D/USBList: UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/005,mVendorId=38672,mProductId=30784,mClass=255,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=255,mManufacturerName=null,mProductName=null,mVersion=2.0,mSerialNumber=null,mConfigurations=[
UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=160,mMaxPower=50,mInterfaces=[
UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=255,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=255,mEndpoints=[
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=2,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=131,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=4,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=133,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=6,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=135,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=8,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=255]
UsbEndpoint[mAddress=137,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=16,mInterval=5]]]]
```

If I understand, I have to communicate with the UsbEndpoint via the UsbInterface but I've only 4 serial ports but get 9 UsbEndpoints.

So I don't know what to do next to identify the good UsbEndPoint to communicate with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Most USB-serial converters are supported by the Android Things Peripheral I/O API, so the first thing I would recommend you check is whether or not your converter shows up as a `UartDevice` under the peripheral list:

```
PeripheralManager.getInstance().getUartDeviceList()
```

The devices will usually how up with name like `USB1-1:1.0`.

If your device is not supported by this subsystem, then you may need to dive deeper into the USB APIs. Let's decode your endpoint descriptor output a bit more. Your device has 8 endpoints of type "Bulk" (`mAttributes=2`), and one of type Interrupt (`mAttributes=3`). The bulk endpoints are paired for each serial channel (one for input, one for output). You would need to read each endpoint's direction value to know for sure (not printed in the log). The order in which they are listed most likely indicates the pairing for each channel.

You will then need to contact the manufacturer of your USB device and find the datasheet that describes the protocol they use to transfer data. The device/interface classes are all `0xFF` (`255`), which means "vendor-specific". In essence, it means they don't conform to a standard USB device class and they need to provide documentation on the protocol.